# Need Help To Convert This Small Php Function To Python

Tags: php, python, function

```
function imei(){
    $nu = "3514512";
        $num = rand(1111111,9999999);
    $s = ''.$nu.''.$num.'';

    // Add a zero check digit
    $s = $s . '0';
    $sum = 0;
    // Find the last character
    $i = strlen($s);
    $odd_length = $i % 2;
    // Iterate all digits backwards
    while ($i-- > 0) {
        // Add the current digit
        $sum+=$s[$i];
        // If the digit is even, add it again. Adjust for digits 10+ by subtracting 9.
        ($odd_length == ($i % 2)) ? ($s[$i] > 4) ? ($sum+=($s[$i] - 9)) : ($sum+=$s[$i]) : false;
    }
    $ime = (10 - ($sum % 10)) % 10;

    $imei = ''.$nu.''.$num.''.$ime.'';

    return $imei;
}
```

I need to convert this function into python, i tried alot but always failed with many errors.

I came up with this :

```
def imei():
nu = "8613750"
num = random.randrange(1111111,9999999)
s = '' + nu + '' + num + ''
s = s + '0'
sum = 0
i = len(s)
odd_length = i % 2

while i > 0: 
    sum += s[i]
    if (odd_length == (i % 2)): elif (s[i] > 4): elif (sum += (s[i] - 9)): (sum += s[i]) else false
    i -= 1

ime = (10 - (sum % 10)) % 10
imei = '' + nu + '' + num + '' + ime + ''

return imei
```

**ERROR:**

File "functions.py", line 30
if (odd_length == (i % 2)): elif (s[i] > 4): elif (sum += (s[i] - 9)): (sum += s[i]) else false

**EDITED AFTER SUGGESTION:**

```
def imei():
nu = '8613750'
num = str(random.randrange(1111111,9999999))
s = '' + nu + '' + num + ''
s = s + '0'
sum = 0
i = len(s) - 1
odd_length = i % 2

while i > 0:
    sum += s[i]
    if odd_length == i % 2:
        if s[i] > 4:
            sum += s[i] - 9
        else:
            sum += s[i]

i -= 1

ime = (10 - (sum % 10)) % 10
imei = '' + str(nu) + '' + str(num) + '' + str(ime) + ''

return imei
```

print(imei())
                            ^

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: edited please check

Answer (score 0):

Based on the PHP code, the `if` statement should like like this:

```
if odd_length == i % 2:
    if s[i] > 4:
        sum += s[i] - 9
    else:
        sum += s[i]
```

Also, the code inside the `imei()` function needs to be indented. Indentation is non-optional in Python.

Comment: thanks and yes if statement is working now but it still has too many errors, can you please help me in fixing them all and yes i already maintained indentation but quora is just removing them all

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functions.py", line 43, in <module>
    print(imei())
  File "functions.py", line 29, in imei
    sum += s[i]
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: That's because sequences (including strings) in Python are 0-indexed. You need to change `i = len(s)` to `i = len(s) - 1` as suggested by @Manideep Karthik.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the logic but try something like this.

```
import random
def imei():
    nu = "8613750"
    num = random.randrange(1111111,9999999)
    s = '' + str(nu) + '' + str(num) + ''
    s = s + '0'
    Sum = str(0)
    i = len(s) - 1
    odd_length = i % 2

    while i > 0: 
        Sum += s[i]
        if (odd_length == (i % 2)) or (s[i] > 4):
            Sum += str(int(s[i]) - 0)
        else :
            Sum += s[i]

        i -= 1

    ime = (10 - (int(Sum) % 10)) % 10
    Imei = '' + str(nu) + '' + str(num) + '' + str(ime) + ''

    return Imei
```

Comment: showing this error: TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: clearly s is a string here and not an integer. It is working for me.

Comment: File "functions.py", line 29, in imei
    sum += s[i]
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: @NandanTRsn, are you even trying to run the _exact same_ code as posted here?

Comment: i = len(s) - 1 should have solved the problem. Upvote my answer if you find it helpful.